# Why can't I store a string with an accent character in this mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to save the a line of text into a mysql column. The line of text contains a word with an accent character:

`Labrèche`

The table is encoded using utf8mb4, as you can see from the following statement:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE forge.fba_shipments_reports\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: fba_shipments_reports
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `fba_shipments_reports` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `report_line` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've checked the session variables for my Laravel application's connection, and it also shows utf8mb4:

```
>>> DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%'"));
=> [
     {#3346
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_client",
       +"Value": "utf8mb4",
     },
     {#3351
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_connection",
       +"Value": "utf8mb4",
     },
     {#3344
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_database",
       +"Value": "utf8",
     },
     {#3352
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_filesystem",
       +"Value": "binary",
     },
     {#3349
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_results",
       +"Value": "utf8mb4",
     },
     {#3340
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_server",
       +"Value": "latin1",
     },
     {#3341
       +"Variable_name": "character_set_system",
       +"Value": "utf8",
     },
   ]
```

When I try to save this string, I get an error:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '/xE8che/x09G...' for
>   column 'report_line' at row 1 (SQL: insert into
>   `fba_shipments_reports` (`report_id`, `report_line`) values (foo,
>   Labr�che))'

Why is this character causing problems if I'm using utf8mb4 encoding? I thought this encoding was supposed to support these characters.

Comment: Oh, am I supposed to `utf8_encode` BEFORE inserting into the database?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your SQL, everything looks to be correct `CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.  I have a feeling something inside the Laravel framework is getting clever for you behind the scenes.  Try a query with plain old PDO and prepared statements and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @AlexBarker if I `utf8_encode` the string first, it works correctly. Is that how it's supposed to work or should encoding not be necessary if the table charset is set correctly?

Comment: Actually, the string is coming from an Amazon MWS report, I wonder if that's causing the problem. Maybe Amazon isn't sending the data encoded correctly, so by encoding it myself before saving it works correctly.

Comment: `utf8_encode()` is very poorly and misleadingly named. The accurate name would be `convert_iso8859_dash_1_to_utf8_without_caring_if_the_input_acutally_IS_iso8859_dash_1_in_which_case_corrupt_the_data()`. Use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) instead and explicitly define the input encoding. Also worth noting that ISO8859-1 is only distinguishable from MS cp1252 by the missing/mismatched/borked chars when you confuse the encodings.